# How to modify the file name of flutter_windows.dll

Tags: flutter, windows

I am using flutter to develop on the windows platform. When my program is ready to be released, I see flutter_windows.dll file in the program directory. I know this is the engine file of flutter. Now I don't want my users to know that my program is developed with flutter, so I want to modify the file name, such as "xxxx.dll". In addition, there is a flutter_assets directory in the data directory in the same directory, and I also want to change its name. Please tell me how to modify it, please help me, thank you.

I don't know where to start. Does this require recompiling the flutter engine?